# Removing trailing spaces inside <af:inputListOfValue>

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am looking for a way to trim my leading and trailing spaces inside my af:inputListOfValues components. I can access the View Criteria programmatically, and trim all my values from VOImpl custom class, but I am not sure how to expose it to the actual component. Is the a way to expose my custom methods to the LOV component? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here it tells how to create the LOV https://o7planning.org/en/11517/creating-lov-list-of-values-in-oracle-adf-bc, but it doesn't tell how to customize it programmatically.

Comment: Trimming the field in the VOImpl getter should work. Did you try ?

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't work. I think I have to actually expose these methods to the component's fields, so that they can be invoked. Unfortunately, I can't figure it out.

Comment: If you inputListOfValues is based on a VO then trimming the field in the VORowImpl getter function will work 100%

Comment: How do you actually invoke all these methods from the LOV component. I am trimming inside VORowImpl, but it is not being called.

Comment: The getters in the VORowImpl are called everytime the sql query is executed. Are you sure your LOV is based on this VO ? You can use the jdev debugger to go step by step and verify.

Comment: I am trying to trim the search criteria that you enter inside your LOV component. But i think I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In order to trim the values inside my LOV component I had to override executeQueryForCollection. This way I was be able to access my parameters and trim them.

```
@Override
protected void executeQueryForCollection(Object qc, Object[] params, int noUserParams) {
    ArrayList<Object[]> alParams = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    //Pass along any explicit (user entered) parameters for the query. Also some implicit parameters.
    if(params != null && params.length > 0){
        for (Object o : params) {
            alParams.add((Object[])o);
        }
        //Access the value of each object and trim it
        for (Object[] p: alParams){
            if(p.length > 1){
                p[1] = trimCriteria(p[1]);  
            }  
        }
        Object[] trimParams = alParams.toArray();
        super.executeQueryForCollection(qc, trimParams, noUserParams);
    } else {
        super.executeQueryForCollection(qc, params, noUserParams);
    }

}


public Object trimCriteria (Object searchCriteria){
    if(searchCriteria instanceof String)
    if(searchCriteria != null){
        searchCriteria = ((String)searchCriteria).trim();
    }
    return searchCriteria;
}`
```